# How to convert the online documentation with html links to pdf?

Tags: html, pdf, documentation

There are many documentaion on internet or user guides which have no pdf.
They have the table of contents and links.
Is there any way that i can convert them to pdf for printing for offline reading

EDIT: IF i can get some script code where i can give the http address of the wiki documentaion and that script generats the Single page of the html links it will be great.

thanks

Comment: what OS are you using? and do you have any browser restriction?

Comment: I am using windows 7 ,, no i don't have restriction

Comment: sorry but this is not a programming question

Comment: I was looking for some programming thing which can grab the html link and put contents in one page.

Comment: Then why don't you ask the question like that? Because asked like this you don't gonna get "programming things" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this popular addon for Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pdf-download/